# 5 standard 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that at least 3 of them

Tags: probability, combinatorics

5 standard 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that at least 3 of them show a 6 as the top face? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Perhaps try the question for "*exactly 3 of them show a 6*" and add that to "*exactly 4 of them show a 6*" etc... Utilize what you should have been taught about binomial distributions.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: As for "*I'm dumb*", don't think that.  That isn't helpful to anyone, especially you, for you to say or think that.  You just haven't had the practice and haven't had the material "click" in your head yet.  That alone doesn't mean you will never get it.

Comment: As for your tag choices in posting here, don't use the [education] tag just because it is a question that appeared *during* your education.  It is supposed to be a tag *about* the process of educating someone, a question about the *pedagogy* of education.  Questions such as "*How frequently should tests be administered*" or "*what to do if two or three students don't understand the material which the rest of the class all understands?*"  Almost always such questions are off topic here and should be asked at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you don't know where to start, one way to start is by trying to solve a simpler version of the same problem. For example:

- 5 standard 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that **exactly** 3 of them show a 6?

If you don't know where to start with that one, then maybe try:

- 5 standard 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that **exactly 5** of them show a 6?

If that's still too hard, maybe this?

- **2** standard 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that **exactly 2** of them show a 6?

When you do find one you can solve, ask yourself what you would need to be able to solve the next one up. Maybe you will think of something. Maybe you will remember something you read in your book.  Maybe if you look over the last chapter of the book now, you will notice something that seems helpful that you forgot.

But even if not, you can now ask someone else and say:

> I can solve (this problem) but not (that one). I think I need to (do whatever) but I don't know how. Can you help?

That puts you in a much better position than "I don't know anything", and the people you asked will have a better idea of how they can help you.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: P.S. I love your avatar.